# How to start another terminal task first?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I have linux mint and I very long c++ program. It takes approximately one hour to finish, and I have to execute 4 different ones.

I don't want to come back every hour just to type in terminal to start another one, so is there any way to make it automatically?

Comment: Put all the command lines in a script file, one command per line, and run that. Or you can seperate the commands with semicolons instead of newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type all the commands, separated by newline or semicolon:

```
command1; command2; command3; command4
```